# Blender 2.80 material differences

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, import, color

Recently i decided using 2.80 for my project created in 2.79 and experienced some issues with materials.
Imported materials from 2.79 seem to work differently on 2.80 to those created in a clean 2.80 blend file. My main issue is that i cant toggle nodes off on any materials of imported blend files to get those kinda "simple-mode" materials. Creating new materials behaves the same.

Also i dont understand the differences of "Viewport display" and "Surface". They both have colors which could be set. i just want flat colors as materials with metalic shading or transparency nothing too special. i also dont use any textures.

**clean 2.80 material:**

[image: clean 2.80 material]

**imported 2.80 material:**

[image: imported 2.80 material]

Comment: Your clean 2.8 material is for use in eevee, your imported 2.8 material is for use in Cycles.

Comment: Thank you for your response on my question. However unfortunately this doesnt help me much with my issue. As i said earlier I still dont understand why each material got created.
I need to know how to change them, and what is going on there in general to get a basic understanding of it.